# integral sign in $$ vs align

Tags: amsmath, integral

Why output of \int defer when used in $$--$$ vs align?
How to make output from latter look more like former?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
$$\int_V \mu(u,v,w) \,du\,dv\,dw $$
\begin{align}
  \int_V \mu(u,v,w) \,du\,dv\,dw
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]
PS: I am typesetting on overleaf.

Comment: Welcome! I get the expected size of `\int`. Please, make a complete example reproducing the issue, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Welcome! You should not use `$$ ... $$` anyway (and it helps the readers tremendously if differential d's are upright).

Comment: Are you by any chance comparing `$\int$` (one pair of dollars) with the display math version that you get with the `align` environment?

Comment: the left hand version is the inline math with single dollar. Please always post a _complete_ small document that shows the problem, that avoids this kind of error in the question.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat don't let egreg see you ask for upright d, he'll get very cross.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What do you mean by "get"? ;-) Users are strange here, some put pineapple on a pizza, others do not typeset differential d's upright. Hard not to see a pattern. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be reproduced from your code. However, the LaTeX run shows several errors:

```latex
! LaTeX Error: Environment align undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.6 \begin{align}
```

After this error, TeX tries to recover as best it can.

You ***need*** `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the document preamble.

Besides, never use `$$` in LaTeX, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/4427)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\int_V \mu(u,v,w) \,du\,dv\,dw
\end{equation*}
Some text in between.
\begin{align}
  \int_V \mu(u,v,w) \,du\,dv\,dw
\end{align}

\end{document}
```